# C# XML Serialize object of Array object "There was an error generating the XML document."

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm having a problem with the c# XML serialization system it's throws an Ambigus exception,

> There was an error generating the XML document.

Now i have a Class that contains refferences to other classes and arrays of the other classes

E.G

```
namespace P2PFileLayout
{
    public class p2pfile
    {
        public FileList FileList;
        public StatusServer StatusServer;
        public String Hash;
    }
}
namespace P2PFileLayout.parts
{
    public class StatusServer
    {
        public Auth Auth;
        public Servers Servers;
    }
    public class Servers
    {
        public Server[] Server;
    }
    public class Server
    {
        public bool AuthRequired = false;
        public string Address;
    }
    public class Files
    {
        public File[] File;
    }
    public class File
    {
        public string FileName = "";
        public int BlockSize = 0;
        public int BlockCount = 0;
    }
    public class Directory
    {
        public string Name;
        public Files Files;
        public Directory[] Dir;
    }
    public class Auth
    {
        public AuthServer[] AuthServer;
    }
    public class FileList
    {
        public Files Files;
        public Directory[] Directory;
    }
}
```

My Example data

```
        // create the test file
        testFile = new p2pfile();

        // create a fake fileList
        testFile.FileList = new P2PFileLayout.parts.FileList();
        testFile.FileList.Directory = new P2PFileLayout.parts.Directory[1];
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0] = new P2PFileLayout.parts.Directory();
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Name = "testFolder";
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files = new P2PFileLayout.parts.Files();
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files.File = new P2PFileLayout.parts.File[2];
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files.File[0] = new P2PFileLayout.parts.File();
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files.File[0].FileName = "test.txt";
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files.File[0].BlockSize = 64;
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files.File[0].BlockCount = 1;
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files.File[1] = new P2PFileLayout.parts.File();
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files.File[1].FileName = "test2.txt";
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files.File[1].BlockSize = 64;
        testFile.FileList.Directory[0].Files.File[1].BlockCount = 1;

        // create a fake status server
        testFile.StatusServer = new P2PFileLayout.parts.StatusServer();
        testFile.StatusServer.Servers = new P2PFileLayout.parts.Servers();
        testFile.StatusServer.Servers.Server = new P2PFileLayout.parts.Server[1];
        testFile.StatusServer.Servers.Server[0] = new P2PFileLayout.parts.Server();
        testFile.StatusServer.Servers.Server[0].Address = "http://localhost:8088/list.php";

        // create a file hash (real)
        HashGenerator.P2PHash hashGen = new HashGenerator.P2PHash();
        testFile.Hash = hashGen.getHash();

        treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Loading..."));

        Classes.CreateTreeView ctv = new Classes.CreateTreeView();
        ctv.BuildTreeView(testFile.FileList, treeView1);
        treeView1.AfterCheck += new TreeViewEventHandler(treeView1_AfterCheck);
```

Now that is not as complicated as mine in terms of dept as my i loop objects so dir has support for more dirs but thats just an example

Then i'm serializing to a string var as i want to do a little more than just serialize it but here is my serialization

```
private string ToXml(object Obj, System.Type ObjType)
        {
            // instansiate the xml serializer object
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(ObjType);
            // create a memory stream for XMLTextWriter to use
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            // create an XML writer using our memory stream
            XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            // write the object though the XML serializer method using the W3C namespaces
            ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, Obj);
            // close the XMLWriter
            xmlWriter.Close();
            // close the memoryStream
            memStream.Close();
            // get the string from the memory Stream
            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer());
            // remove the stuff before the xml code we care about
            xml = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(60)));
            // clear any thing at the end of the elements we care about
            xml = xml.Substring(0, (xml.LastIndexOf(Convert.ToChar(62)) + 1));
            // return the XML string
            return xml;
        }
```

Can any one see why this is not working or any clues as to why it would not work normally

Comment: Your code does exactly what it does, but you have no detail what you **want** this code to do... Consider updating your question with your actual goal.

Comment: @Martin Barker - I tried your code and worked perfectly. The sample classes your provided need bit adjustments.

Comment: @Martin Barker - see my edit, your member variables declaration was incorrect.

Comment: @Sandy don't answer the question by editing it. I was wondering why it doesn't throw any exception till I saw your comment.

Comment: @L.B - my edit isn't the answer, its only fixes the compile time error. Actual error message in the title will only show up while serialization.

Comment: @Sandy It works without an error on my machine.

Comment: @L.B - yes. same here. Martin Barker - is it working for you?

Comment: Sorry Sleep was needed (there are no compiler time errors)
updating to add my class layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing it manually?
What about this approach?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

```
Test test = new Test() { Test1 = "1", Test2 = "3" };
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(test.GetType());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
x.Serialize(ms, test);
ms.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: That should be a comment not an answer, and the reason is in the question i need to save the content into a variable

Comment: You could use your class instead of my Test class :-)

Comment: @MartinBarker, this is answer to your question in the title... sort of. Note that it is very hard to guess that you "need to save the content into a variable" from your question.

Answer (score 0):

As for the ambigous message, take a look into the inner exceptions. XML serialization errors use innerexception a lot, and you usually have to look to all levels of InnerExceptions to know what is really happening.